# Memory Leak in CCOMVariant

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, com

There is a leak when we run our applications. We ran UMDH to find the cause of leak. The leak points to the below call stack,

```
+   40448 (  70832 -  30384)    917 allocs  BackTrace42C19860
+     560 (    917 -    357)    BackTrace42C19860   allocations

    ntdll! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+153EB
    OLEAUT32!VariantCopy+13D
    ATERegistry!CATERegValue::put_Value+28 (<source_code_location>, <line_number>)
    ATERegistry!CWinRegManager::GetWinRegValues+1C9 (<source_code_location>, <line_number>)
```

So the place of leak points to the below line,

```cpp
hr = pValue->put_Value(varValue)
```

The method is as follows,

```cpp
GetWinRegValues()
{
    ...
    vector<BYTE> btValue;
    btValue.resize(_MAX_PATH); (//where _MAX_PATH = 260)
    ...
    res = RegEnumValue(hkey, dwIdx, szName, &cbName, 0, &dwType, &btValue[0] , &cbValue); //Enumerate the values of the current key in the Windows Registry
    ...
    if (res == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        CComVariant varValue;
        switch (dwType)
        {
            case REG_DWORD: // Yes
                varValue = *(long*) &btValue[0];
                break;
            case REG_EXPAND_SZ: // Yes, expand with ExpandEnvironmentStrings
                varValue = (LPTSTR) &btValue[0];
                break;
            case REG_SZ: // Yes
                varValue = (LPTSTR) &btValue[0];
                break;
            default:
                continue;
        }
        ...
        CComPtr<IATERegValue> pValue;
        hr = CComCreator< CComObject< CATERegValue> >::CreateInstance(NULL, IID_IATERegValue, (void**)&pValue);
        ...
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
            hr = pValue->put_Value(varValue)  // This is the line which UMDH shows as leak
        }
```

The implementation of `put_value` is as follows:

```cpp
STDMETHODIMP CATERegValue::put_Value(VARIANT newVal)
{
    m_Value = newVal;
    switch(newVal.vt) {
        case VT_BSTR:
            if(wcschr(newVal.bstrVal, OLESTR('%')))
                m_Type = REG_EXPAND_SZ;
            else
                m_Type = REG_SZ;
            hr = S_OK;
            break;
        case VT_I4:
            m_Type = REG_DWORD;
            hr = S_OK;
            break;
        default:
            hr = Error(OLESTR("Value must have variant type VT_I4 or VT_BSTR."), IID_IATERegKey, E_FAIL);
            break;
    }

    return hr;
}
```

where `m_value` is `_variant_t m_Value; //VARIANT value of the current ATERegValue`

How do I fix this leak?

Comment: CComVariant has no memory leak by itself. You can of course create leaks if you misuse it. The only suspect I spot is m_Value = newVal. What is m_value?

Comment: If `m_Value` is also a `VARIANT` then you need to do memory management yourself (e.g. call `SysFreeString()` if the old value holds a `BSTR`). Better to use a `_variant_t` and then the memory management is handled for you.

Comment: m_value is of type _variant_t

Comment: _variant_t (Visual Studio) is similar to CComVariant (ATL). There should not be any leak here. There must some other code we don't see that causes leaks. You can try to just run that piece of code in a loop and see if memory goes up.

Comment: @JonathanPotter "*If `m_Value` is also a `VARIANT` then you need to do memory management yourself*" - better to use `VariantCopy()`, if not `_variant_t` or `CComVariant`

Comment: @Rayner there is no leak assigning a `VARIANT` to a `_variant_t`. The leak report says the leaked memory is from `VariantCopy()` which `_variant_t::operator=` uses, so the only way `m_Value` could be leaking is if it is being overwritten improperly afterwards, or its destructor is not being called. The code shown does not do either of those, so the problem has to be code that you have not shown.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I ran only this method in loop and looks like there is no leak in it. I don't know why UMDH is pointing to it. I recollected the data again and still it points to that code. Maybe I will try to use LeakDiag and see whether it shows a real leaking call stack.